# Calculating Probabilities from a Venn Diagram

Tags: probability

A city that has 150,000 inhabitants sells three different newspapers (A, B, and C). It's known that 10% of the population read A; 30% read B; 5% read C; 8% read A and B; 2% read A and C; 4% read B and C; 1% read A, B, and C.

It's also known that A and B are "daily" newspapers, while C is a "nightly" newspaper.

If 1 person is randomly selected, what's the probability of him belonging to the group that:

a) read only one of the three newspapers. 
b) read a maximum of 2 newspapers. 
c) don't read any of the 3 newspapers. 
d) read at least one daily newspaper and the nightly newspaper.
e) read only one daily newspaper and the nightly newspaper.

First, I constructed a Venn diagram to organize the information given (D stands for daily and N stands for nightly):

[image]

For a), I added up the sections of the diagram which don't include any intersection:

28500+1500+0 = 30,000; then I divided that result by omega to get my first answer:

P(only read one of three newspapers) = 30,000/150,000 = 0.2

For b), I added up everything inside the diagram except the intersection between all three sets:

P(read maximum 2) = 28500+1500+10500+1500+4500+0 = 46.500/150.000 = 0.31

For c), I simply divided the number of people outside the three sets by omega:

P(read none) = 102,000/150,000 = 0.68

How can I solve d) and e)?

Comment: The same way as the other problems.  Find which regions in the venn diagram correspond to the phrase "at least one daily newspaper and the nightly", add the values together, and finally divide by the sample space size.  Similarly for part (e).

Comment: For d), I would interpret "at least one daily newspaper" as the union between A and B. "And" the nightly would be the intersection with said union. Therefore, my result would be 6000/150000 = 0.04?

Comment: Do not confuse union with symmetric difference.  Why 6000?  Are you adding two numbers together or three?  If you are just adding two numbers together, why not the third one?

Comment: You're right; then it would be 7500/150000 = 0.05

Comment: for e) the answer would be 0? Can't see how only A or only B could intersect with C

Comment: The key word here is *or*.  The people who read exactly one daily newspaper and the nightly newspaper are exactly those people who read at least one daily newspaper and the nightly newspaper but doesn't read all three.  It will not be zero.  You will again figure out which regions correspond to this and add like before.

Comment: In that case, would it be (1500+1500+28500+4500)/150000 = 36000/150000 = 0.24 ?

Comment: Do the 28500 that you refer to read the nightly newspaper?

Comment: No... then it would be (4500+1500)/150000 = 6000/150000 = 0.04 ?

Answer (score 1):

> If a person is randomly selected, what is the probability that he or she belongs to a group that reads at least one daily newspaper and the nightly newspaper?

The two daily newspapers are $A$ and $B$; the nightly newspaper is $C$.

**Method 1:**  We want $p((A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C))$. Since
$$p((A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)) = p(A \cap C) + p(B \cap C) - p(A \cap B \cap C)$$
we obtain 
$$p((A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)) = 0.02 + 0.04 - 0.01 = 0.05$$

**Method 2:** If we instead work with the Venn diagram, we can find the number of people who read at least one daily newspaper and the nightly newspaper by finding 
$$|A \cap B^C \cap C| + |A^C \cap B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$$
Dividing that number by the city's population gives the desired probability.
$$p((A \cap B^C \cap C) \cup (A^C \cap B \cap C) \cup (A \cap B \cap C)) 
= \frac{1500 + 4500 + 1500}{150000} = \frac{7500}{150000} = 0.05$$

> If a person is randomly selected, what is the probability that he or she belongs to a group that reads only one daily newspaper and a nightly newspaper.

**Method 1:** We want $p(((A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)) \setminus (A \cap B \cap C))$.  Since 
$$p((A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)) = p(A \cap C) + p(B \cap C) - p(A \cap B \cap C)$$
we obtain
\begin{align*}
p(((A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)) \setminus (A \cap B \cap C)) & = p(A \cap C) + p(B \cap C) - 2p(A \cap B \cap C)\\ 
& = 0.02 + 0.04 - 2 \cdot 0.01\\
& = 0.04
\end{align*}

**Method 2:** If we instead work with the Venn diagram, we can find the number of people who read only one daily newspaper and the nightly newspaper by finding
$$|A \cap B^C \cap C| + |A^C \cap B \cap C|$$
Dividing that number by the city's population gives the desired probability.
$$p(A \cap B^C \cap C) \cup (A^C \cap B \cap C)) = \frac{1500 + 4500}{15000} = 0.04$$

Answer (score 0):

D. the number of persons who read atleast one daily and night is=5%
                                                                =7500
   probability= 7500/1,50,000 =0.05
E. no. of persons who read only one night and one daily is =4%
                                                           =6000
   probability =6000/150000 = 0.04